# How to fetch values from a dictionary and apply or replace that to the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, apply

I have one dataframe [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5dNH.png)

I have created a dictionary:

Uplift = {
1: 'Significant',
0: 'Insignificant',
0.5: 'Poor'
}

I want to change 1 to Significant, 0 to Insignificant and 0.5 to Poor for a particular column say the Uplift adjacent to Sales. I have tried this:

Sales_Uplift.iloc[0:1,2:3].apply(Uplift.values())

but getting error:

AttributeError: 'Significant' is not a valid function for 'Series' object

**and also tried**

if Sales_Uplift[(Sales_Uplift['Uplift'] == 1) | (Sales_Uplift[' Uplift'] == 1) | (Sales_Uplift['  Uplift'] == 1)]: 'Significant'
elif Sales_Uplift[(Sales_Uplift['Uplift'] == 0)  | (Sales_Uplift[' Uplift'] == 0)  |  (Sales_Uplift['  Uplift']  == 0)] : 'Insignificant'
else: Poor

**but getting error:**

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().